# How to launch an associated watch app from an IOS application

Tags: ios, watchkit

How do I launch an associated `Watch App` from an `IOS App`?

I do see questions where the user flow is in reverse, where the `Watch App` starts the `IOS App` in the background. However I want the reverse. I want to launch the `Watch App`, make it visible on the watch when the associated `IOS App` is running.

My current user experience is not good; I launch the `IOS App` from the Phone, then fiddle with the watch to find the associated `Watch App`.

The current `IOS App` plays music at times, and I have added the `Now Playing View`. I have also noticed that when I start the watch application "not programatically", some minutes later (after the watch goes to sleep and raised  again to awake) the default music player `Watch App` is made the current watch application when playing music via the `IOS App`.

I would have preferred that the associated watch application is active on the watch, and that the `Now Playing View` controls the music.

The watch application has two views/pages where the user would swipe to move to the next page. The first page has some text and the second page has the `Now Playing View`

It would be far better, if the users starts the `IOS App` and auto launches the associated `Watch App`.

I am not sure what the design decisions are regarding this. Perhaps a Notification needs to be sent, and the user can then decide whether to launch the `Watch App`.

Please assist by giving brief API calls to make or adjusting properties in the plist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by sending a workout configuration to your watch app via
[startWatchAppWithWorkoutConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1648358-startwatchappwithworkoutconfigur)

I'm not sure it would get past the App Review for non workout apps. You might have to call this method twice to reliably start the app, due to a timeout: [forum discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86380)